# Rename Duplicate XML Tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some xml XML Document with duplicate tag names like below ::

```
<ROOT>
    <RECORD>
        <ID>A1</ID>
        <NAME>Name1</NAME>
        <ADDRESS>StreetName</ADDRESS>
        <ADDRESS>CityName</ADDRESS>
        <ADDRESS>State</ADDRESS>
        <ADDRESS>321</ADDRESS>
        <PHONE>12345</PHONE>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <ID>A1</ID>
        <NAME>Name1</NAME>
        <ADDRESS>StreetName</ADDRESS>
        <ADDRESS>CityName</ADDRESS>
        <ADDRESS>State</ADDRESS>
        <ADDRESS>123</ADDRESS>
        <PHONE>12345</PHONE>
    </RECORD>
</ROOT>
```

So i have to get total address but when i am applying XSLT i am getting only First  Tag Value.
Is there any possibilty to change that ADDRESS tag names to apropriate Tag names like STREET, CITY,STATE and ZIP Tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:reps>
  <rep pos="1">STREET</rep>
  <rep pos="1">CITY</rep>
  <rep pos="1">STATE</rep>
  <rep pos="1">ZIP</rep>
 </my:reps>

 <xsl:variable name="vReps"
      select="document('')/*/my:reps/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ADDRESS">
  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select=
     "count(preceding-sibling::ADDRESS)+1"/>
  <xsl:element name="{$vReps[position()=$vPos]}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<ROOT>
    <RECORD>
        <ID>A1</ID>
        <NAME>Name1</NAME>
        <ADDRESS>StreetName</ADDRESS>
        <ADDRESS>CityName</ADDRESS>
        <ADDRESS>State</ADDRESS>
        <ADDRESS>321</ADDRESS>
        <PHONE>12345</PHONE>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <ID>A1</ID>
        <NAME>Name1</NAME>
        <ADDRESS>StreetName</ADDRESS>
        <ADDRESS>CityName</ADDRESS>
        <ADDRESS>State</ADDRESS>
        <ADDRESS>123</ADDRESS>
        <PHONE>12345</PHONE>
    </RECORD>
</ROOT>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<ROOT>
   <RECORD>
      <ID>A1</ID>
      <NAME>Name1</NAME>
      <STREET>StreetName</STREET>
      <CITY>CityName</CITY>
      <STATE>State</STATE>
      <ZIP>321</ZIP>
      <PHONE>12345</PHONE>
   </RECORD>
   <RECORD>
      <ID>A1</ID>
      <NAME>Name1</NAME>
      <STREET>StreetName</STREET>
      <CITY>CityName</CITY>
      <STATE>State</STATE>
      <ZIP>123</ZIP>
      <PHONE>12345</PHONE>
   </RECORD>
</ROOT>
```

**Explanation**:

Overriding the identity rule with a template matching `ADDRESS` and generating an element according to the position of this `ADDRESS` element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the name if you want but that won't give you anything you didn't already have. Having the names street city state is no different to getting the nodes 
address[1], address[2], address[3]

Comment: But i am not getting like address[1], address[2],address[3]. i have with same tag name address for all these.

Comment: Yes, you do. So when you select them in the XSLT you can address them as:   <xsl:value-of select="address[1]"/> <xsl:value-of select="address[2]"/>. THe number in brackets is the occurance of the tag, so address[1] is the first address, address[2] the second address etc. If you have a problem with that you need to look up xpath axis